# Local Variable fm Cannot Be Resolved to a Type

Tags: android

In my app, I am creating tabs that use Fragments and a pageAdapter. In my TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity class, I get the error that:

```
fm cannot be resolved to a variable TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.java  /LoginAndRegistration/src/com/example/loginandregistration  line 47 Java Problem
```

When I follow the quick fix options I chose to create a local variable and then it tells me to initialize fm (fm stands for FragmentManager by the way) but then it sets it to **null**
I define fm in my PageAdapter here:

```
public class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

// Declare the number of ViewPager pages
final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;

public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
super(fm);
}
```

So my question is:
Should I follow the quick fix? If so, what should I change the **null** value to? OR Should I change something in my PageAdapter class? Here is the TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.java as well:

```
package com.example.loginandregistration;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import com.example.loginandregistration.MyPageAdapter;

public class TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

// Declare Variables
ActionBar mActionBar;
ViewPager mPager;
Tab tab;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from dashboard.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);

    // Activate Navigation Mode Tabs
    mActionBar = getActionBar();
    mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Locate ViewPager in activity_main.xml
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    // Capture ViewPager page swipes
    ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener ViewPagerListener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);
            // Find the ViewPager Position
            mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    };

    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPagerListener);
    // Locate the adapter class called ViewPagerAdapter.java
    MyPageAdapter viewpageradapter = new MyPageAdapter(fm);
    // Set the View Pager Adapter into ViewPager
    mPager.setAdapter(viewpageradapter);

    // Capture tab button clicks
    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {

         @Override
         public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
             // Pass the position on tab click to ViewPager
             mPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
         }

         @Override
         public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         }

         @Override
         public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         }
     };



    // Create first Tab
    tab = mActionBar.newTab().setText("Tab1").setTabListener(tabListener);
    mActionBar.addTab(tab);

    // Create second Tab
    tab = mActionBar.newTab().setText("Tab2").setTabListener(tabListener);
    mActionBar.addTab(tab);

    // Create third Tab
    tab = mActionBar.newTab().setText("Tab3").setTabListener(tabListener);
    mActionBar.addTab(tab);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide the fragment manager from the `Activity` to the adapter constructor:

If you use the support library:

```
MyPageAdapter viewpageradapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
```

Comment: I now get the errors that "Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8)" How can I fix this lint error without having to change my entire min to 11?

Comment: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=29f8lck&s=5#.UkZOphbnZAg This is where they are just as a reference if needed.

Comment: `ActionBar` is available from API 11, so same thing here, use the support library: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html

Comment: So would I change any of my imports or would I do something such as add a Suppress? When you say use the support libary are you saying that ActionBar is included in the support libary? (Sorry for the misunderstanding)

Comment: Yes import what you need from the support libraries. The default action bar is working for API > 10. If you want it to be working on previous API, you need to add support libraries v4 or v7 in your project. Check this: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Comment: I added the v4 support libary to my project but when I went to add the action bar from the support libary into my imports I couldn't find it. What would the import be?

Comment: For ActionBar it is v7, as I said it is explained here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html. Otherwise you can have a look the the Sherlock action bar.